# ImportError: cannot import name QgsVectorFieldSymbolLayer

Tags: python, qgis

I am using QGIS 1.7.4., downloaded April 2012, but receive an import error loading the class QgsVectorFieldSymbolLayer. As i understand this class has been added in the Python bindings on 2011-11-15. Does anybody know whether this class has already been included and if so, what else can be wrong?

No, while executing a Python script.
First line:

```
from qgis.core import (QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry, QgsDataSourceURI, QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFieldSymbolLayer, QgsSymbolLayerV2AbstractMetadata, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsMapLayer, QgsField, QgsComposition, QgsComposerLegend, QgsComposerLabel, QgsRectangle, QgsFeature, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2, QgsSymbolV2, QgsRendererRangeV2, QgsMarkerSymbolLayerV2)
```

All classes are imported okay, except QgsVectorFieldSymbolLayer.

Comment: When do you get this error?  On loading QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

The [QGIS 1.7.4 release does not have a .sip file](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/tree/release-1_7_4/python/core)  for that binding.

It is, however, [present in the master branch](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/tree/master/python/core), having been added about 5 months ago, as you have noted. Currently, QGIS is in a feature freeze for version 1.8. The developers have also decided to not have a 1.8 branch, but create a release from the master branch. So, at this time, I not quite sure if that class will be available via Python in 1.8 (though I surmise it will be).

You might consider posting your question to the [the developers list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer).

Comment: If you want to work with the new binding, you could try compiling QGIS yourself. Not too bad once you have the prerequisites installed. All in the [well-annotated INSTALL doc](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/INSTALL). If you're on Mac OS X 10.7.3, you might take a look at a simple bash script I wrote for [generating a nightly build](https://gist.github.com/1684071).

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I understand it just needs some time.
I will post the question to the developers list.